# Filtering our results with Only one attribute value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to filter out customers with accounts which have only one status - 3.
I do not need results (customers) who have other status codes than 3.

Example (This customer should be out of scope):

```
Customer    Account_number  Account_status
a                 XX002           2
a                 XX001           2
a                 XX003           3
a                 XX005           4
a                 XX004           1
```

This should be in:

```
Customer    Account_number  Account_status
b                 XX007           3
b                 XX008           3
```

I have tried IN, NOT IN, all but cannot find the right way.
I am using Oracle SQL developer, is there some function for this type of filtering?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Use a where clause:

```
select * from customers where Account_status = 3
```

Comment: This actually gives all of the other results, I would need only Account_status = 3

Answer (score 0):

Try using `not exists`

```
select * from customers a where not exists 
(select 1 from customers b where a.customer=b.customer and account_status<>3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `Not Exists`

select * from customer C where not exists
(select 1 from customer D where C.customer=D.customer and acount_status <>3)

Answer (score 0):

I would use window funtions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             sum(case when account_status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer) as cnt_3
      from example e
     ) e
where cnt_3 <> 1;
```

You can also do this with a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select e.*
from example e
where (select count(*)
       from example e2
       where e2.customer = e.customer and e2.status = 3
      ) <> 1;
```